# Filter Datatable with linq by considering deleted rows

Tags: linq

I have a following datatable -

```
static DataTable GetTable()
{
  //
  // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
  //
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

//
// Here we add five DataRows.
//
table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
return table;
}
```

// taken from following link
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable

On PageLoad I do the following code -

```
DataTable dt = GetTable();
dt.AcceptChanges();
dt.Rows[0].Delete();
var t = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dataRow => dataRow.Field<string>        ("Drug").Equals("Enebrel"));
```

It throws an error, that unable to get the data from deleted rows.

Is there any way to filter tell linq that do not take into account deleted rows.

Thanks,
Daljit Singh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could specify to exclude the deleted row in your linq with something like this

```
var t = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dataRow => dataRow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted &&...
```

That should do the trick